# In field of view with SpriteKit rotational coordinate system

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, sprite-kit, trigonometry

SpriteKit's rotational coordinate system is very difficult to work with, needless to say.

Mathematically, it's a complete disaster.

I have a field of view, *x*, such that the leftmost view is *θ+x*, and the rightmost being *θ-x*, *θ* being the zRotation of the sprite.

How would I check if an angle is in another's field of view?

```
let λ be atan2(test.y - char.y, test.x - char.x)
let θ be char.zRotation
if λ in θ - x, θ + x
    return true
```

[image: This makes no sense]

Answer (score 0):

If you clamp the angles to between PI and -PI then the math is a bit simpler:

```
let PI=CGFloat(M_PI)

var spriteAngle:CGFloat=0
let fieldOfView:CGFloat=0.5
var targetAngle:CGFloat=0

while spriteAngle>PI {
   spriteAngle=spriteAngle-2*PI
}
while spriteAngle < -PI {
    spriteAngle=spriteAngle+2*PI
}
while targetAngle>PI {
    targetAngle=targetAngle-2*PI
}
while targetAngle < -PI {
    targetAngle=targetAngle+2*PI
}

let lowerBound=spriteAngle-fieldOfView
let upperBound=spriteAngle+fieldOfView

if lowerBound <= targetAngle && targetAngle <= upperBound {
    //angle in range
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to determine if a node is within the field of view of another node. It is fairly straightforward if you convert the angles to be in [0, 2*pi).

```
    // 1/2 of the field of view
    #define kFieldOfViewDiv2    (M_PI/8)

    // Calculate differences in x and y between the sprites
    CGFloat dx = sprite2.position.x - sprite.position.x;
    CGFloat dy = sprite2.position.y - sprite.position.y;
    // Determine angle of sprite2 relative to sprite
    CGFloat theta = atan2(dy, dx);
    // Theta in [0, 2*pi)
    if (theta < 0) {
        theta = theta + M_PI*2;
    }
    // Alpha in (-2*pi, 2*pi)
    CGFloat alpha = fmod(sprite.zRotation,2*M_PI);
    // Alpha in [0, 2*pi)
    if (alpha < 0) {
        alpha = alpha + M_PI * 2;
    }
    // Calculate |theta-alpha|
    CGFloat diff = fabs(theta-alpha);
    // Handle wrap near 0 degrees
    if (diff > M_PI) {
        diff = 2*M_PI - diff;
    }
    // Field of view test
    if (diff <= kFieldOfViewDiv2) {
        NSLog(@"In field of view");
    }
```